# ER diagram software

Tags: software-recommendation, database

[ER](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity-relationship_model) diagram software for Ubuntu?

Comment: Could you please explain what is lacking in Dia, so that we can answer with the most suitable alternatives?

Comment: https://drawerd.com is a online erd tool.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

### Dia

Dia is a GTK+ based diagram creation program for GNU/Linux, Unix and Windows released under the GPL license. For more information visit [the Dia project page](https://web.archive.org/web/20130929012736/https://projects.gnome.org/dia/)

To install Dia in all currently supported versions of Ubuntu open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install dia
```

Comment: workflows with inkscape???

Comment: why not? See this http://www.ioncannon.net/utilities/123/10-tips-for-creating-good-looking-diagrams-using-inkscape/

Comment: What does "Install electric sheep" mean? The link heads to an auto-download page for dia. Is it some jargon?

Answer (score 27):

I've found [MySQL Workbench](http://wb.mysql.com/) to be most useful for creating "ER" diagrams.

[image]

Though the format is only MySQL Workbench specific I can take a diagram created in Workbench and export it to SQL and execute it against any number of SQL servers.

[image]

If you're working with MySQL this tool also doubles as an Administration and Querying tool as well providing the added benefit of integration between the three.

Comment: It's a good tool, a good explanation, but I will use DIA.
Thank you!!!!

Comment: Extremely buggy (lost my work twice, crashed 5 times total), and printing to a PDF has unacceptable font quality issues (and I would assume a real printer also).

Comment: WB is not only buggy in behavior but in look and feel too (try to use it in a HiDPI monitor and you will see). There is a bug report about that since *2009* without any work on it (and so many other marked as duplicated).

Comment: can you export and execute on Oracle?

Answer (score 5):

[Umbrello](https://umbrello.kde.org/) can also create ER-Diagrams besides most other UML diagrams. In addition it allows you to export the Diagrams in form of code (i.e. in this case SQL).

Comment: umbrello http://www.umbrello.org/index.php and is for KDE if you use gnome it install a lot of KDE dependency

Answer (score 1):

try to use [Astah Comunity](http://astah.change-vision.com/en/index.html),  the application was able to create ER diagrams, class diagrams, etc.To develop applications that application is very suitable. I even heard the professional version could generate java code to class diagram and generate sql code for the ER diagram.

that application was built using java, so the application is multi platform.

Comment: the astha comunity FREE only support UML Modeling Tool the other thing you coment is the paid one